# Pile up of ornaments in J.S.Bach's BWV 935

Tags: j-s-bach, baroque-period, ornaments

These are bars 19-23 in J.S. Bach's BWV 935, from the *Sechs kleine Präludien für Anfänger auf dem Klavier*:
[image]

Can anyone spell out for me what should be played for that E in bar 23 adorned with a grace note and a mordent and a turn all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What it's trying to say is:

1. grace note: "play f on the downbeat with the duration of an eighth note"
2. trill sign: "trill between f and e"
3. turn: "end the trill in a turn leading to the next beat.

Here is a "slow" realization of the ornaments.

[image: Notated example with 32nd note trill/turn]

FWIW, I looked at three other editions on IMSLP, and all three wrote (the equivalent of) an eighth note f on the downbeat followed by a quarter note e with a trill indication; no turn.

Comment: Thanks! The picture in the question is from a Henle edition.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez there are two manuscripts [listed at RISM](https://opac.rism.info/metaopac/search?searchCategories%5B0%5D=-1&q=BWV%20935&View=rism&Language=en) that have a link to an online viewer.  One seems to be the source of the Henle edition; the other matches Aaron's description.